# A function that checks for how many times each element appears in an array

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I am making a function that lists an array and says how many times each element appears.

What I have thought of on my own so far is i should loop through the array and there should be a counter to keep track of the number of times it appears and then a second array to place the value of that counter in correspondence to the value in the first array.

But i cant figure out a algorithm to search to see if each value was repeated inside the loop.

Comment: Post some code and magic will happen

Comment: Your approach sounds generally correct. What is this an array of? ints? strings?

Comment: it is an array of ints, ill try to see if i can write some code for what ive come up with so far

Comment: I see you are new to stackoverflow.  Welcome!  Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: ***[SO question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)***

Comment: i dont have a minimal understanding, i was never taught this at all i dont even know where to start. nevertheless ill try my best to make something but i dont think it will be acceptable (T_T)

Comment: wait a bit I will send you some code and explanation

Comment: hint: sort the array, then use the approach that you mentioned. So, if next number is larger than the current number which you are counting, it means that you have found all the occurrences of the current number, because all the numbers after it are greater, since they are in ascending order

Comment: @user3027779 - see new, simplified code example here per your comments in new post that I assume you deleted. It would still be good if you were to post your code here by editing your post.(anything you have done)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code example has been simplified, and has more comments

Here are some suggested steps:
***1)*** assuming `int a[]` is sorted (for ease of counting) (ascending or descending, it does not matter).
***2)*** Create separate arrays to keep *found results* where
***first*** one, `num[]` stores the unique value, and
***second*** `cnt[]` stores the number of that value found.
***3)*** loop through sorted array.
***4)*** in loop, store unique value, and count of occurrence in keep array.

The sorting routine `qsort()` is a concept you will learn later if you are just getting started, (don't get distracted with it for now) ***but do observe the part*** of this example addressing your question, look for the comment *"Look Here"*.  As described above, it loops through the array, and stores information about when numbers change, and how many of each there are.

***Here is a small code example:***

Look at the comments to know where to focus attention on setting counters etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define sizea 100 //to make variable declarations easier and consistent

    int num[sizea];//unless array has all unique numbers, will never use this many
    int cnt[sizea];//same comment

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b);//DISREGARD for now (it just works)

int main(void)
{    //a[] is created here as an unsorted array...
    int a[sizea]={1,3,6,8,3,6,7,4,6,9,0,3,5,12,65,3,76,5,3,54,
                  1,3,6,89,3,6,7,4,6,9,0,4,5,12,65,3,76,5,3,54,
                  1,9,6,8,3,45,7,4,6,9,0,89,5,12,65,3,76,5,3,54,
                  6,3,6,8,3,6,7,4,6,9,0,23,5,12,65,3,76,5,3,54,
                  1,3,6,90,3,6,7,4,6,9,0,5,5,12,65,3,76,5,3,54};

    int i, j, ncount;

    for(i=0;i<sizea;i++) cnt[i] = -1;
    for(i=0;i<sizea;i++) num[i] = -999;

    //sort array (AGAIN - DON'T spend time on this part, it just sorts the array)
    qsort(a, sizea, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

    // a is NOW SORTED, in ascending order, now loop through...
    j=0; //start num and cnt arrays at first element and set ncount to 1
    num[j] = a[0];
    cnt[j] = 1;
    ncount = 1;//start off with at least one of the first number
    //***Look Here***//
    for(i=0;i<sizea-1;i++)//"sizea - 1" so we do not go past a[sizea-1] elements
    {                     //a has sizea elements, indexed from 0 to sizea-1
                          //or a[0] to a[99]
        if(a[i+1] != a[i])
        {
            j++;  //new unique number, increment num[] array
            num[j] = a[i+1];
            ncount = 1; //different number start over
            cnt[j] = ncount;//initialize new cnt[j] with 1
        }
        else
        {
            cnt[j] = ++ncount; //increment cnt, apply it to array
        }
    }
    i=0;

    //We now have a list of unique numbers, and count of each one.  Print it out
    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        printf("number %d occurs %d times\n", num[i], cnt[i]);
    }
    getchar(); //so results will show. 

    return 0;
}
//Note num[j] and cnt[j] correspond to each other
//num contains a unique number
//cnt contains the number of occurrences for that number

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

For the array example included, here are the results using this code:

[image]

Comment: why sort when you can do this in O(n) steps??

Comment: coz without sorting it will take O(n2) steps

Comment: @ΘεόφιλοςΜουρατίδης how would you do this in O(n)?

Comment: Your code uses non-standart libraries, structs (like me) and function arguments, what a nice example for a newbie in C as you claim he is. You also have some text uncommented...

Comment: both ansi_c.h and windows.h

Comment: i tried this and it didnt work because visual studios 2012 says it cant open the source file <ansi_c.h>

Comment: Take out my references to headers and use your own.  My environment is also an ANSI C compiler, but there are always minor variations between compilers.  Just use the header files you would need to compile an ANSI C program.  All code in this example is ANSI C.  Try just `#include <stdio.h>` and see if that works for you.

Comment: Just found ***[link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/)*** that says `qsort()` function requires `#include <stdio.h>`.  Include that also if you have not done so yet.

Comment: Okay thanks it really works!! I understand how you got the counter to work too, you were right about it being answered lol. Thank you! :D

Comment: Glad to help. I hope this was not too arduous. Stay on course and it becomes more fun. (once the fundamentals are learned.)

Comment: Its alittle fun now, but i cant wait to get past the fundamentals

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a pseudocode, to help you with the algorithm which you said you are unable to understand. I hope this will encourage you to start the code.

```
//store the first number in a variable and find 
//how many times it occurs in the array, repeat this for all
//the elements in the array

int current = arr[0];  
int i=0, count=0;  

for(i=0; i < arr.length;i++){ // loop through all the elements of the array

     if(arr[i]==current)   {
         count++;  // if current number is same as the number you are looking for
                   // then increment the counter
   } // end of if-loop
}
```

Comment: thanks im figuring everything out now i'll comment if i have problems

Comment: i updated it with the code you helped create but im still having problems

Answer (score 0):

At first you must define a list with the integers you have and their number of appearances

```
struct linked_list {
    int value;
    int numOf;

    linked_list *next;
};
```

then you must have the functions to operate that list, like creating a list, pushing an item to it, finding a node in that list and print it the list.

```
linked_list* newItem(int value) {
    linked_list * temp = (linked_list *)malloc(sizeof(linked_list));

    (*temp).value = value;
    (*temp).numOf = 1;

    return temp;
}

linked_list* findItem(linked_list *head, int value) {
    linked_list *counter = head;

    while (counter != NULL && (*counter).value != value) {
        counter = (*counter).next;
    }

    return counter;
}

void pushToList(linked_list **head, linked_list *item) {
    (*item).next = *head;
    *head = item;
}

void printList(linked_list *head) {
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("%d:%d\n", (*head).value, (*head).numOf);
        head = (*head).next;
    }
}
```

You must study lists in order to understand how do they operate.
Then your code logic goes like this:

```
linked_list *duplicate = NULL;
int i;

int list[11] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2 };

for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    linked_list *current = findItem(duplicate, list[i]);

    if (current == NULL)
        pushToList(&duplicate, newItem(list[i]));
    else
        (*current).numOf++;
}

printList(duplicate);

while (1);

return 0;
```

(I must free the list but I didn't in this code :P)

I make a list with the items/elements that may be duplicate. I start from the beginning of the array. I check the first element of the array and then I check if it is on the duplicate list. If I can't find it in the list, I make a new record to the duplicate list with 1 number of appearances. Then I check the rest, if they appear in the list I add the number of appearances by one, if they are not, I make a new record. At the end my list will have every number and their number of appearances.

This code takes O(n) steps if your data difference is a constant. If your data difference grows with the number of elements it would take more steps.

This approach is better than sorting algorithms in many occasions in terms of number of step to execute and memory allocation.

Comment: _This approach is better than sorting algorithms in many occasions in terms of number of step to execute and memory allocation_ ***Really***?  Isn't that similar to saying _it can be really code outside, unless of course its warm_...  Also, you are really suggesting using _linked lists_ for a person who has suggested they are just getting started with C?

Comment: If he is just getting started with C and he has that kind of problems, then he must move on lists

Comment: Lets observe some ability to walk before we put OP on a ***[Hayabusa](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7f/2007ModelwitLE.jpg/300px-2007ModelwitLE.jpg&imgrefurl=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suzuki_Hayabusa&h=200&w=300&sz=17&tbnid=AkI_H-92U1KAeM:&tbnh=90&tbnw=135&zoom=1&usg=__7PQGznote0KsFXq1Ab1453IQLfU=&docid=ksNCSi3ZTMiwmM&sa=X&ei=SVaSUrDiGubBigLBnIDwBg&sqi=2&ved=0CDcQ9QEwBA)***.