# C - Sorting values in arrays read from files

Tags: c, arrays, function

So my program is supposed to read in values from a file, set those into an array, then find the number of times each value is found as well as the value found the most frequently. The second function (called createVArray) is where I need to read in the values and store in the array. I'm trying to implement a technique found here: [A function that checks for how many times each element appears in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177496/a-function-that-checks-for-how-many-times-each-element-appears-in-an-array) which is why there are some variables not being used yet. I'm also having problems with trying to print out the array to even see if my loop is working. Thank you and here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100

int main(){

int votes[100]={0},i,num[100],count[100];

//reading in file
FILE *input, *output;
input = fopen("votes.txt","r");

//error checking that file opened correctly
if (input == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file!\n");
    exit(1);
}


system("pause");
return 0;
}

void createVArray(FILE *input, int votes[]){

  int i,j,k,temp;

    //storing values into array
  while(fscanf !=30){
    for(i=0;i<=MAX;i++){
      fscanf(input,"%d",&votes[i]);
        printf("%d\n",votes[i]);

    }
  }//bubble sorting array
  for(j=1;j<MAX;j++){
    for(k=0;k<MAX -1; k++){
        if(votes[k]>votes[k+1]){
            temp=votes[k];
            votes[k]=votes[k+1];
            votes[k+1]=temp;
          }

      }
  }
//  for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
//  count[i] = -1;
//  }
//  for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
//  num[i]= -999
//  }
// in the middle of adding in technique to sort
}


int getMaxVote(int votes[]){


}

void printSummary(int votes[]){
    printf("Choice        Num Votes\n");
    printf("-----------------------\n");

    printf("-----------------------\n");


}
```

edit: I added in the rest of that code I found and brought the previous code from createVArray into main(), but it's still giving me issues, here's my main() right now.

```
    int main(){

int votes[100]={0},i,num[100],count[100];

//reading in file
FILE 
*input, *output;
    input = fopen("votes.txt","r");

    //error checking that file opened correctly
    if (input == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
     int j,k,temp,ncount;

    //storing values into array
  while(fscanf !=30){
    for(i=0;i<=100;i++){
      fscanf(input,"%d",&votes[i]);
        printf("%d\n",votes[i]);

    }
  }//bubble sorting array
  for(j=1;j<100;j++){
    for(k=0;k<100 -1; k++){
        if(votes[k]>votes[k+1]){
            temp=votes[k];
            votes[k]=votes[k+1];
            votes[k+1]=temp;
          }

      }
  }
  for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    count[i] = -1;
    }
  for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    num[i]= -999;
    }
  j=0;
  num[j]=votes[0];
  count[j]=1;
  ncount=1;
  i=0;
  for(i=0;i<100-1;i++){
    if(votes[i+1]!=votes[i]){
        j++;
        num[j]=votes[i+1];
        ncount=1;
        count[j]=ncount;
      }
    else{
        count[j]=ncount++;
    }
  }
 for(i=0;i<j;i++){
    printf("number %d occurs %d times\n",num[i],count[i]);
 }
 getchar();

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Editing in case anyone else comes across this. Here is my solution that I came up with a tutor and taking some time with a cooler head:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//defining constant
#define size 100
//prototypes of functions
int createVArray(FILE *input,int votes[],int count[],int counter);
int getMaxVote(int count[]);
void printSummary(int count[],int counter,int high);
int main(){
    //intializing variables
int votes[100]={0},i=0,count[21]={0}, j,k,n,length, high=0,counter=0;
//reading in file
FILE *input;
    input = fopen("votes.txt","r");

    //error checking that file opened correctly
    if (input == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //setting all values in count array to 0
    for(k=0;k<22;k++){
        count[k]=0;
    }
    //calling in functions
    counter = createVArray(input,votes,count,counter);
    high = getMaxVote(count);
    printSummary(count,counter,high);


system("pause");
return 0;
}
int createVArray(FILE *input,int votes[],int count[],int counter){
     int i=0;
     while(votes[i] != 30){
    //scanning in values from file to array
    fscanf(input,"%d",&votes[i]);
        //switch statement to keep count of frequency of values
        switch(votes[i]){
            case 1:
                count[1]++;
                break;
            case 2:
                count[2]++;
                break;
            case 3:
                count[3]++;
                break;
            case 4:
                count[4]++;
                break;
            case 5:
                count[5]++;
                break;
            case 6:
                count[6]++;
                break;
            case 7:
                count[7]++;
                break;
            case 8:
                count[8]++;
                break;
            case 9:
                count[9]++;
                break;
            case 10:
                count[10]++;
                break;
            case 11:
                count[11]++;
                break;
            case 12:
                count[12]++;
                break;
            case 13:
                count[13]++;
                break;
            case 14:
                count[14]++;
                break;
            case 15:
                count[15]++;
                break;
            case 16:
                count[16]++;
                break;
            case 17:
                count[17]++;
                break;
            case 18:
                count[18]++;
                break;
            case 19:
                count[19]++;
                break;
            case 20:
                count[20]++;
                break;
        }
        //counting total number of values
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
} 
int getMaxVote(int count[]){
    int high,i=0;
    high = 1;
    //calculating most frequently voted for value
for (i=2; i<=20; i++){
    if (count[i] > count[high])
        high = i;
    }
    return high;
}
void printSummary(int count[],int counter,int high){
 int k=0;
 //printing out top 2 lines
 printf("Choice          Num Votes\n");
 printf("-------------------------\n");
 //for loop to print out individual values and 
 //frequency of said values
 for(k=1;k<21;k++){
    printf("%2d%20d\n",k,count[k]);
 }
 //continue printing last lines
 printf("-------------------------\n");
 printf("Total Votes         %d  \n",counter);
 printf("winning option     %d\n",high);
 printf("-------------------------\n");
}


        }
```

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking for

Comment: Sorry. I'm having issues with the values not being saved into the array properly, and am also having issues with sorting those values to be able to be printed with the number of times they occur. Example: "14   occurs  5 times" @JohnField

Comment: `fscanf !=30` : Any sense to this is? also `for(i=0;i<=100;i++){` --> `for(i=0;i<100;i++){`

Comment: you could start with adding the missing prototypes for the sub functions  Then the compiler would not be making guesses about parameters and return values.   enabling all the warnings when compiling would have allowed the compiler to tell you about the problems that need fixing before trying to execute the code  when the code cleanly complies, then we can really help you with the debugging